# How do I use the SET command in SQL to delete the leading characters to create a new attribute?

Tags: sql

I want to use UPDATE in SQL to populate a new attribute based on an exiting attribute using SET.  what command do I use to get rid of the first 39 characters?  I want to make: https://www.hmdb.org/marker.asp?marker=11 into: 11

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a minute to review how to ask a good question. It will help you get a great answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUBSTRING(@LINK, 40)`

This makes a substring of the link starting from the 40th character, effectively removing the first 39 characters.

Without knowing your table structure, it is hard to give a full command on that.

Let's say you have a table named `table` and it has 2 columns `link` and `marker`. The command will be

```
UPDATE table SET marker = SUBSTRING(link, 40);
```